# Disallow Comma Validation Rules

Tags: template, validation, requirejs-config.js, custom-validation

I am using this mixin for the custom validation rules in the below template for the first and last name

Template:

```
/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml
```

require js :

```
  var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Magento_Customer/js/name-validation': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Js file :

require(
[
'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator',
'jquery',
'mage/translate'
], function(validator, $){
'use strict';

```
    validator.addRule(
        'validate-checkname',
        function (value) {
            let checkComma = value.includes(',');
            return !checkComma;
        },
        $.mage.__("Please enter valid name avoid using comma")
    );
    return validator;

});
```

But not working when I edit the first name and last name with the comma in the customer Address Book edit.

Comment: have you checked your custom validation appearing in js sources?

Comment: Yes its appearing. Its working but after saving the address but its working but I want to work this js before saving

Comment: Ohh i see you are facing the issue cux whenever you focusout the input the data is pusing to local storage 

you need to intercept and add validation before the data is pushed to localstorage

Comment: I also add sequence of the modules